# Conditional type throws error that property doesn't exist

Tags: typescript

I'm exporting an empty interface like so:

```
export interface Test {}
```

Then exporting a conditional type:

```
export type TestProperty = Test extends {TestProperty: unknown} ? Test["TestProperty"] : {testData: unknown}
```

But get the error: `error TS2339: Property 'TestProperty' does not exist on type 'Test'.`

The reason for this is that i'm writing a library and trying to override the interface by declaring a module globally in a different directory like so:

```
declare module "testmodule" {
  export interface Test {
    TestProperty: {
      testingboolean: boolean
    }
  }
}
```

I've seen this work before, but wondering if I'm missing something so the bundler can work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe like this? https://tsplay.dev/mAJOXW

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKpnMw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?